# Git: get name of files commited?

Tags: git, github

I've used `git log`, but it does not give the name of files commited, just the `sha code`.

Is there a way to see the name of the files that were commited?

I need to be sure what is commited, and then push the right files to github. I don't want to push files, and after that deleting some of them.

Unfortunatle, the commit message does not mention the files commited localy.

**`git diff` does not return results.

**EDIT 1**

`git status` shows some deleted files to be commited. As you know, git also records deleted files.

What i need is the name of the files that were commited in the last commit. I don't get that with `git status`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git log` has the `--name-only` option, that will *add* the filenames committed to the log-entry.

To get a "log" consisting only of SHA-hashes and filenames use:

```
git log --name-only --pretty=%H
```

to get only the files touched in the last commit, use:

```
git log --name-only --pretty="" HEAD~1..
```

to include the status/action, use:

```
git log --name-status --pretty="" HEAD~1..
```

Answer (score 0):

the command you want is: `git status`

Answer (score 0):

Try `git status` to give you the file names of what has recently been committed but not yet pushed.

**Source**:
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-status

**EDIT 1**

`git log --name-status HEAD^..HEAD`

This will provide you with a listing of the modified files from the last commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git show`:

```
git show HEAD
```

shows the last commit diff,

```
git show HEAD~1
```

shoes the penultimate commit diff, and so on.

As I've said rather than showing the filenames only, git show can show a diff (which is what I prefer when checking a commit)

Answer (score 0):

Once it is commited, you need to compare your commit with other.

To know what was in your last commit:
 git diff --stat HEAD~1

To know what was committed in other older commit:
 git diff --stat shaNumber~1 shaNumber

However, try gitk. It is a frontend program very easy to use that it gives you this kind of info.

Answer (score 0):

`git show <commit>` will show you the diff and commit message for one commit in isolation. If the commit you're interested in is the current `HEAD`, then you can just use `git show` with no arguments.

`git log --stat` will show you diffstats, with the filenames and how many lines were added/removed to them in each particular commit.

`git log -p` will show a complete diff for each commit below the log entry.

`git log --name-only` will just show the names of changed files.

Answer (score 0):

To see the name of the files changed post commit,

```
$git diff --stat
```

To check the name of the files post adding, before committing,

```
$git diff --cached
```